# Complex sets: factoring into circle

Tags: complex-numbers

How must $|z|=3|z-1|$ be factored so I end up with a circle, plugging in $z=x+iy$ seems to just up with square roots everywhere. Detailed steps is much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Square it up!..

Comment: Have u tried its a mess

Comment: And use that $|z|^2=z \bar{z}$.

Comment: Yes, we can also calculate with complex numbers, using $|z|^2=z\bar z$:
$$z\bar z=9(z-1)\overline{(z-1)}$$
which you prefer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align*}
 z \overline{z} = 9 (z - 1)(\overline{z}-1) = 9 z \overline{z} - 9 z - 9 \overline{z} + 9 \\
8 z \overline{z} - 9 z - 9 \overline{z} + 9 = 0
\end{align*}
Now a circle is supposed to look like $$(z - a)(\overline{z} - \overline{a}) = r^2= z \overline{z} - a \overline{z} - \overline{a} z + |a|^2$$
So taking our old relation and diving by 8, we get
\begin{align*}
z \overline{z} - \frac{9}{8} z - \frac{9}{8} \overline{z} + \frac{9}{8} = 0 \\
z \overline{z} - \frac{9}{8} z - \frac{9}{8} \overline{z} + \frac{81}{64} = \frac{81}{64} - \frac{9}{8} = \frac{9}{64} 
\end{align*}
So with some algebra we have a circle centered at $\frac{9}{8}$ with radius $\frac{3}{8}$.

For fun: you can view the locus of solutions $S$ as the inverse image of the unit circle of the fractional linear transformation $z \mapsto \frac{z}{3z-3}$. Conjugate points are sent to conjugate points and the center of $S$'s conjugate is $\infty$. Infinity maps to $1/3$ and the conjugate about the unit circle is $3$, so the inverse of that is $8/9$. Similarly I can find what is sent to 1 and that'll give me a radius.

Comment: Thanks for showing all the steps much appreciated!!!

Answer (score 0):

Using $z=x+iy$, we get
$$x^2+y^2=|z|^2=9|z-1|^2=9((x-1)^2+y^2).$$